# Regression Testing in Titanium Alloy

Tags: ios, unit-testing, titanium, regression, appcelerator

What is the best technique for regression testing in titanium alloy? Please provide suggestions.Basically I have some webservices the populate data in my iOS app made in Titanium Alloy.I want some automatic testing way that test my app for crashes or invalid values or null values.

Ali

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at [Tony Lukasavage's implementation of Mocha](https://github.com/tonylukasavage/ti-mocha).

/John

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [tishadow](https://github.com/dbankier/TiShadow), which is the only test-framework of titanium/alloy that I tried and found works, it wrapped( or used Tony's mocha-ti) . others are out-dated or not-mature enough.

However, tishadow has somehow learning curve.  take a look at : http://appium.io/